# Can we spin a top in vacuum?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, vacuum, gyroscopes

What happens to a top if we spin it in vacuum. Will it have any difference to rotating in a normal surface to a surface in vacuum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A spinning top is a gyroscope; it doesn't need air. The gyroscopes on the Hubble telescope work just fine up there.

Comment: So there would be no difference in rotating it in a vacuum and in free surface

Comment: Other than lost rotation due to air friction, nope. The top would function the same in both instances.